# How to use matSort in a reusable table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to pass sorted Data to my reusable table component using Mat-Sort
this is the line of code I'm using in my parent.component.html:

```
<app-table matSort  
  [colData]="{'headers':headerData}" 
  [rowData]="rowData" 
  (matSortChange)="sortData($event)"
></app-table>
```

But how do I "catch" the matSortChange event?
In my table.component.html I tried

```
<table 
  matSort 
  (matSortChange)="onClick($event)" 
  id="vehicles" 
  border="1" 
  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm"
></table>
```

While in my table.component.ts i built an event emitter like this:

```
@Output() notify: EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>();
```

called by my onClick method:
`

```
 onClick(event) {
    this.notify.emit(event);
  }
```

But it doesn't sort anything.
How can I catch this event? Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are outputing the event as notify. So you would use it like:

```
(notify)="sortData($event)"
```

In your table component html. "matSortChange" is emitted by matSort which you have already used with onClick.

Comment: I also tried this but It still doesn't work, i tried putting a console.log(event) in onClick(event) method but it doesn't seem to be called

Comment: I was wrong, it's called and the output is {active: "Id", direction: "desc"} from material Sort, maybe I need to change that

Comment: Okay, thanks to your advice I managed to fix it, thank you!